# Site similar to Ruby Quiz, but for PHP?

Tags: php

Does anyone know of a quiz site similar to ruby quiz (http://www.rubyquiz.com/), but for PHP?

I figure the best way to learn php is to actually work on a script, at the moment, I can't think of a script that I would need so I'm looking for some ideas, maybe something thats not too hard.

Comment: Depending on how ambitious you're feeling, you could just use the quizzes on Ruby Quiz, and convert them to PHP. Comparing the "PHP way" to a different language might actually be more helpful. Or it could be so confusing and frustrating as to totally turn you off of server-side development for good.

Comment: I'd prefer if there was a site that also included the solution as well. Thats the great thing about Ruby Quiz, it provides solutions from users so you can see the different ways of making the script.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at phpGolf - http://phpgolf.org/

Not only are there problems to solve, but it'll challenge you to do it in as few bytes as possible.