# Are there any good PHP quiz for testing php knowledge?

Tags: php

Something like this quiz for javascript. http://perfectionkills.com/javascript-quiz/

I have searched it but I came across only on newb quiz.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Site similar to Ruby Quiz, but for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964593/site-similar-to-ruby-quiz-but-for-php)

Comment: So? Duplication is about the question, not answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the Zend Certification, that's fun.

http://static.zend.com/topics/PHP-5-3-Study-Guide-v1.pdf

Comment: added the free beta Study Guide, there's lot of question in it.

Comment: This is a good document with tests in the certification guide http://static.zend.com/topics/PHP-5-3-Study-Guide-v1.pdf (Hi Brice ;-))